# how does one "select a boot disk" in ubuntu 20.04 install

Tags: installation, ubuntu-20.04

I have a volume group consisting of 4 x 1TB disks.   I have created LVs for /, /var/ and /boot all formatted ext4.  On other machines I have done installs on simply mounting /boot seems to be all that is required to satisfy the requirement.

In older distros (e.g 18.04) there was an option to select a partition as bootable.

Edit:  I have a vague memory of having this problem a while back and an even vaguer memory that the issue was that that Dell server had an internal USB drive and the machine would insist on using it as a boot device if there was a drive inserted.

Does that make any sense.  Getting the stick removed from the machine is none trivial -- it is in a remote data centre.

Answer (score 0):

It should still be there but I'm sure if you can boot from an LV, that might be why the option won't show.

Don't know if it is relevant for you but if the system uses EFI you also need an EFI partition, 100MB FAT will do.

If the stick is causing the problem might the "solution" be to use it as boot device?

Comment: I was using the stick as a boot device and the install kept failing at the point where it was writing the kernel so I tried to set it up to boot from the LVM but for the LV I don't get the option to set it as the boot device,